# Netbeans C++ Program has no terminal output

Tags: c++, netbeans, natty

It's not a weird program. It's a simple C++ Hello World program, and for whatever reason there is no output to the terminal either in the terminal or in the output window. Here's my "code".

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello there peeps!";
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Using Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Comment: Does building the code show any errors?

Comment: Is it being compiled in 64-bit? I remember there being a bug a while back with 64 bit compiled programs and output in Netbeans.

Comment: I didn't think of that. The version of Linux is x86, let me see if I'm compiling the wrong output.

Comment: It looks like it's compiling in x86. The program will run even, but still no output.

Comment: I'm not sure is this a cause of your problem but in Linux there is no command "pause" as in DOS/Windows.  Also you better avoid such C++ code which waits for input from user by calling some OS specific commands like "pause", because it is not portable. Instead you can pause a program in C++ by reading an keyboard input until enter is hit => `cin.get()`. And if you **really really** want to read ANY single keystroke in Linux - you can [look here](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/reading-single-keystroke-on-linux.html).

Comment: According to what @0x69 said [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) is more info why you **shouldn't** use `system("pause");` in any of your programs, not only linux versions.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

**`Project properties -> Run -> Console Type`** and select **`Standard Output`** there.

If this is already selected test with **`Internal Terminal`**.

Comment: Had this problem on Lubuntu 14.04 with NetBeans 8.0.2 and JRE 1.7.0_75, OpenJDK. Your suggestion fixed it, thanks! Could you possibly elaborate what's different between the two? I wasn't even aware of this feature, I assumed NetBeans was already using stdout.

Comment: I assume the internal terminal is some (java / netbeans ?) implemented version that does not flush correctly. Usually as another workaround: run with debugger - this works often too. So i guess the internal terminal uses the error stream in debug mode (auto-flushed) and out stream if running normal (not correctly flushed?). Maybe the *standard output* uses stdout / stderr directly instead or runs as a native process and displays it's output. But this is all only a speculation.

Comment: I wonder if it's also to do with using threads, as I was compiling a program in C++ that uses threads which was already running in debug mode. Before that I hadn't noticed any problems. I wonder why they had to use an internal terminal and couldn't just reuse `stdout`.

Comment: Probably this comes from the cross-platform requirements. Remember: Netbeans has to run on very different systems. Possibly it's an issue not for all operating systems (but i don't know for sure).

Comment: This is not a solution, it's a workaround.  If Netbeans is not creating an external terminal, it means there is a configuration problem with the computer system as a whole.

Comment: Note Lubuntu does not come out of the box with **xterm** installed.  See next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing xterm, that worked for me. (On fedora 18, but Ubuntu should be similar)

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

or

```
sudo yum install xterm
```

Comment: Correct answer.  Note also it's currently necessary to **restart Netbeans** in order for this to take effect.